# How to add icon buttons in days in full-calendar?

Tags: reactjs, calendar, fullcalendar, customization

Need to add view button on full calendar's some day's according to some data

[image]

**React JS**

Tried Exploring Official Documentation of full-calendar,Content Injection etc,
Couldn't find any remarkable solutions for my hiccup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly is the button supposed to be for? There are already `dateClick` and `eventClick` callbacks within the fullCalendar API which allow you to handle someone clicking on a specific day, or a specific event. There are also the Date Nav Links, if you need to handle the calendar going to a detailed view of a specific date when it's clicked. As the comment above says, please clarify the situation so we can give you the best advice. See also [ask]. Thanks.